# Scroll input element to top in a div

Tags: jquery

I'm struggled to move an input element on top in a `scrollable div`.

I want to move an input element to top on focusing the input element, means just after the `div#up` (the initial position of input 1). The div should be scroll down and move the input element to top position.

I tried the below code, but it not works properly,

```
$('input').on('focus', function() {
     console.log($(this).offset());
     console.log($(this).position());
     $('input').removeAttr('style');
     var ot = parseInt($(this).offset().top),
         pt = parseInt($(this).position().top);
     var st = ot - 108; //108 is height of up div
     if (st - pt > 0) {
         st = st - pt;
     }
     if (st < 0) {
         st = ot - 108
     }
     console.log(st, ot, pt);
     $('#container').animate({
         scrollTop: st
     }, 200);
});
```

And I also make an [online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/82ufd6ed/) for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into account current scroll position.

```
$('#container').animate({
     scrollTop: st+$('#container').scrollTop()
},200);
```

Fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82ufd6ed/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I need to add margin of scroll position and then it worked for me,

```
$('input').on('focus', function () {
    var ot=parseInt($(this).offset().top),
        pt=parseInt($(this).position().top);
    var st=ot-108;//108 is height of up div
    var scrollTop=$('#container').scrollTop();// this is I need to add
    if(scrollTop){ // if scroll in container
        st=st+scrollTop; // then add the margin of scroll
    }
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: st
    },200);
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/82ufd6ed/2/)

Comment: You don't really need the if statement, or actually holding the value in a variable (simply wasteful). Other than that, is that any different from my answer?

Comment: No, both are similar. But I didn't see your answer before posting my answer. By the way, I ticked yours, be happy..:)

Comment: Thanks, but really I only tried to see if there is a reason behind your answer :-) (Which turned to be - you simply didn't see mine)

Answer (score 0):

As the container scrolls, the inner input element's position().top changes, so you shall add container.scrollTop. BTW, why did you take `offset` into account? It seems to be useless

```
$('input').on('focus', function () {
    var $container = $("#container");
    var scrollTop = $container.scrollTop() + $(this).position().top;
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTop
    },200);
});
```

And the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82ufd6ed/3/)